# Use Scala and Java test runners simultaneously in IntelliJ

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, cucumber, test-runner

I have a project that uses both Java and Scala test runners. I've created two different Test Sources Folders, one for Java and another for Scala, where I put my two different Test Runners.

However, when I am trying to run my Scala Test Runner it is saying that it cannot find my Cucumber steps (which should come from a dependency which is already in my pom.xml file).

I tried running this on a Scala-only project and everything works fine.

Do you guys have any solution?

Thanks in advance.